# How is not and ! different in Python?

Tags: python, operators

How are the two statements different?

```
if not (answer == "rock" or answer == "paper" or answer == "scissors"):
   quit()
if useranswer == "rock":
   somethingsomething()
```

```
if useranswer != "rock" or useranswer != "paper" or useranswer != "scissors":
   quit()
if useranswer == "rock":
   somethingsomething()
```

If I use the second implementation program quits no matter what input I use, but if I use first implementation it works normally.

Comment: It's because you need to change `or` to `and`.

Comment: This is a logical issue, not a programming issue. Try to trace through the logic of the expression, using some example values for `"useranswer"`.

Comment: If you can't figure it out on your own, please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1):

There are three conditions in your statement (let them be A,B,C).
The first statement is  `not (A or B or C)`, which is equal to `not(A) and not(B) and not(C)`.
The second statement is `not (A) or not (B) or not (C)`. Since both statements evaluate differently, their outcome is different.

Answer (score 0):

Change `or` to and because `or` works if either or both or all is true. And `and` works if all are true. So use `and` instead of `or`.